# How to build a AOSP project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-source

I have imported AOSP code into Android Studio, on building it I am getting some internal errors but Run, Debug buttons are disabled.

[image]

The errors I am getting are:

[image]

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this error and to compile AOSP into Android Studio.
Also can anyone please help to how to convert this project into a Gradle project?

Comment: AOSP doesn't use Gradle at all. It uses GNU Make along with its own systems (ninja, ...).

Answer (score 2):

AOSP used a special format of makefile to build the whole project. If you insist build it on the IDE, you should write a plugin to index the whole makefile on your own.

Focus on something more meaningful. Review and modify the code in IDE, build it in shell, save your time.

Answer (score 2):

To browse and debug AOSP use Intellij IDEA (close to Android Studio) or Eclipse.
AOSP source contains a tool to generate configuration for these two IDE called IDEGen.

> IDEGen automatically generates Android IDE configurations for IntelliJ IDEA
>   and Eclipse. Your IDE should be able to compile everything in a reasonable
>   amount of time with no errors.

[IDEGen README](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/tools/idegen/README)

To debug AOSP Java code take a look at this [article](http://ronubo.blogspot.fr/2016/01/debugging-aosp-platform-code-with.html) (even though it is for Android Studio, configuration is the same for InteliJ IDEA).

Answer (score 1):

Try this - https://developer.android.com/studio/platform

There is an Android Studio version for platform developers (AOSP) , works only on Linux.

Here are some of the features :

- Project Setup Wizard
- Configure your lunch target and platform modules.
- Multi-language Support
- Edit C++, Kotlin, and Java programming languages in the same IDE.
- Java and C++ Debugging Support
- Attach the debugger to an Android process to debug Java and C++ code.